# What do to with String#[] when one needs a method name to call?

Tags: ruby, string

`String#[]` is a very useful method, but is sometimes not possible to use, specifically, for code passed to `instance_eval`.  For example, using the great `rb` tool (at https://github.com/thisredone/rb), if I want to pipe the output of `ls -l` to get the permissions only (admittedly most likely useless, but illustrative of my point) I can do so like this:

```
$ ls -l | rb -l 'split.first'
-rw-r--r--
```

...but if I want to do the same with `[]` it doesn't work:

```
$ ls -l | rb -l '[0..10]'
0..10
# ...
```

How can I use the `[]` operator (method) in cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` method has an alias which does not need workarounds: [slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-slice)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, one has to "trick" it into doing the right thing by using a method call that would normally be redundant. Here are some ways to do that:

```
ls -l | rb -l 'self[0..10]'
ls -l | rb -l 'to_s[0..10]'
ls -l | rb -l 'send :[], 0..10'
ls -l | rb -l 'public_send :[], 0..10'
```

Probably the clearest and most natural way to do this is to use `self`, shown in the first example.